# How can I change a specific row label in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, label

I have a dataframe such as:

```
      0     1    2    3    4    5
0  41.0  22.0  9.0  4.0  2.0  1.0
1   6.0   1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2   4.0   2.0  4.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
3   1.0   2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4   5.0   1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
5  11.4   5.6  3.2  1.6  0.8  1.0
```

Where the final row contains averages. I would like to rename the final row label to `"A"` so that the dataframe will look like this:

```
      0     1    2    3    4    5
0  41.0  22.0  9.0  4.0  2.0  1.0
1   6.0   1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2   4.0   2.0  4.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
3   1.0   2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4   5.0   1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
A  11.4   5.6  3.2  1.6  0.8  1.0
```

I understand columns can be done with `df.columns = . . .`. But how can I do this with a specific row label?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get the last index using negative indexing similar to that in Python

```
last = df.index[-1]
```

Then

```
df = df.rename(index={last: 'a'})
```

Edit: If you are looking for a one-liner,

```
df.index = df.index[:-1].tolist() + ['a']
```

Answer (score 5):

use `index` attribute:

```
 df.index = df.index[:-1].append(pd.Index(['A']))
```